# Background image not showing in ASP.NET Core

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to add a background image to my ASP.NET Core application, but it's not showing.

Even a normal  is not showing.

```
<div class="landing">
    <div class="text-center">
        <h2> app</h2>
        <h4>blah </h4>
        <button class="btn-success">See what we have</button>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
    .landing {
        background-image: url(..\..\wwwroot\images\bkimage.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        height: auto;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll assume the snippet above is from an MVC view. When you're using the `wwwroot` folder, that represents the static content root against which other things can reference (unless you've explicitly changed that). So, the 'wwwroot/images/bkimage.jpg' would just be the root-relative path '/images/bkimage.jpg' off that.

Try the following:

```
background-image: url('/images/bkimage.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

Height attribute must be quantified. For example: `height:400px`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).